# Can I play GTA IV's multiplayer with a different disc (DLC / original game) than my friend?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network, grand-theft-auto-iv

Let's say I have GTA IV (the original game) and my friend has a copy of The Ballad of Gay Tony or The Lost and the Damned. Can we play multiplayer together?

Or what if I have one of the DLC discs, and my friend has the other one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you happen to buy the 2 disc set, one being the original **GTA IV** and the other disc containing **TLAD & BOGT**, and then giving your friend one disc in hopes of playing online together?

The answer is **No.** You will both need a copy of whichever game you two are trying to play together.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if you can both play the DLC while only one of you has it/a disc: No, you cannot. However, you can still both play the original game's Multiplayer.